# CVSNT to CVSNT Migrations

Tags: migration, cvs

Has anybody re-homed a CVSNT installation?

I need to take a CVSNT setup on one ageing server and relocate it to a new shiny server, but i don't have a great deal of experience with this software.

Does anyone know the basic process for moving an entire repository to a new server?  We have 3 base repositories, totaling about 6GB.  Size wise it's not too big, but i need to make sure all the history is migrated correctly.

I've googled around a bit, but not managed to find any info on this kind of move, everyone seems to prefer to write how-to's on moving to Subversion et al....

The CVSNT server is running on windows if that makes a great deal of difference....

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to copy the folders to the new server. CVS control files usually contain relative paths and contain no server-specific information.

See the following link:

http://www.mail-archive.com/cvsnt@cvsnt.org/msg04278.html

Answer (score 1):

Robert Durgin is right, you only have to copy the root folder of your cvs repository.

However, you should be careful to install the same version of CVSNT on the new server, as since 2.5.05 unicode is the default encoding of the server

this forced me to update the server encoding settings on my CVS client (eclipse) .. but I couldn't fix the history encoding and had to revert to 2.5.03

(of course this only applies if your current settings do not use a unicode enconding for the CVS server)